# Emberjs: Setting port in FastbootAppServer script

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using an IISnode instance to host the Fastboot server on my Windows IIS server.

The old version of the fastboot server, Ember-fastboot-server allowed me to set a port number when running the server:
https://github.com/ember-fastboot/fastboot

The port needed is available at process.env.port when hosting on IISnode.

In the new FastbootAppServer, this apparently  isn't possible. How would I go about setting the port number?

Comment: I deleted my answer, as I don't think IISnode would respect unix commands....  I did find an interesting github issue that is tangentially relevant, though: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/46

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the new version of FastbootAppServer (new relative to ember-fastboot-server) is making use of Node clusters. Node clusters aren't supported in IISnode. I believe the solution is to either have a node based hosting solution or go with a middleware solution (eg. Express).